# Order minimized windows within an application

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra

I am currently porting from Windows to MacOS.
One of the cool features I liked about windows is the way it orders multiple windows of the same application.
For example, If you have 10 Chrome windows, it'll order the windows in the same order you opened those windows.
Whereas on a MacOS (I am using High Sierra 10.13.4), the windows are ordered alphabetically. So every time I visit a new website, the order in the application's dock icon would have changed depending on the title of the website. In my opinion, it is very annoying because you will have to scan each and every window to get to the one that you want.

So the question here is, is there a way on Mac where I can make sure that multiple windows of the same application are ordered in the same order that I open those windows instead of ordering it alphabetically ?

Comment: Have you tried activating the "Group windows by application" option on the Mission Control preference pane? I use it because when you go to mission control windows will be arranged by use order.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough before. I am talking about the application icon on the dock. I want the windows in that application to be arranged in the same order that I had opened the windows. Right now it is ordering alphabetically.